# TeamViewer or VNC on slow network?

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, lan, vnc

I have slow network, slow probably because of the tools to filter the traffic and because we run VPN, so sometimes when i run TeamViewer on one PC from the network, i get ID and PW and try to connect from PC out of the network it just accepts ID and PW and hangs, doesnt show anything, i think this is because the network is too slow right ?

So i am wondering would VNC be better solution ? I know that VNC is slow even if you run it on fast LAN network, but i think its slow because its protocol is made like that, other than that i think it will be more reliable than TeamViewer ?

Also suggest me "best" VNC server and client.

Other suggestions are welcome as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Teamviewer has been quite buggy for me, and a little heavy on the CPU, specially when using it in non-Windows machines. [Hamachi](http://hamachi.en.softonic.com/), however, has worked well for me in the past.

I recommend that you use Hamachi to set up a virtual "VPN", and then use the built-in client/servers for remote desktop access. In Ubuntu, use the standard screen sharing, that uses a VNC server/client; in Windows, use remote desktop connection from Microsoft, and on the Mac, use the standard Desktop Sharing service (which is a VPN service/server, but only seems to work perfectly with Apple clients).